# Koin Android: org.koin.error.NoBeanDefFoundException

Tags: android, kotlin, koin

Got that message error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.app.name.application.MainApplication: org.koin.error.BeanInstanceCreationException: Can't create bean Bean[class=com.app.name.general.preferences.Preferences] due to error :
    org.koin.error.NoBeanDefFoundException: No definition found to resolve type 'android.app.Application'. Check your module definition
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5830)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1673)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:172)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6637)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
 Caused by: org.koin.error.BeanInstanceCreationException: Can't create bean Bean[class=com.app.name.general.preferences.Preferences] due to error :
    org.koin.error.NoBeanDefFoundException: No definition found to resolve type 'android.app.Application'. Check your module definition
    at org.koin.core.instance.InstanceFactory.createInstance(InstanceFactory.kt:63)
    at org.koin.core.instance.InstanceFactory.retrieveInstance(InstanceFactory.kt:26)
    at org.koin.KoinContext$resolveInstance$$inlined$synchronized$lambda$1.invoke(KoinContext.kt:85)
    at org.koin.KoinContext$resolveInstance$$inlined$synchronized$lambda$1.invoke(KoinContext.kt:23)
    at org.koin.ResolutionStack.resolve(ResolutionStack.kt:23)
    at org.koin.KoinContext.resolveInstance(KoinContext.kt:80)
    at com.app.name.constants.EnvironmentConstants$initEnvironmentVariables$$inlined$getKoinInstance$1$1.invoke(KoinComponent.kt:114)
    at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(Lazy.kt:131)
    at com.app.name.constants.EnvironmentConstants$initEnvironmentVariables$$inlined$getKoinInstance$1.getValue(Unknown Source:7)
    at com.app.name.constants.EnvironmentConstants.initEnvironmentVariables(EnvironmentConstants.kt:180)
    at com.app.name.application.MainApplication.onCreate(MainApplication.kt:59)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5827)
        ... 8 more
```

But all dependencies were correct.

Also I noticed that modules without `androidApplication()` argument works correctly.

Code looks like:

```
    startKoin(listOf(
            imageManagerModule,
            databaseRepositoryModule
    ))
```

ImageManager works perfectly

```
val imageManagerModule: Module = applicationContext {
    bean { ImageManagerImpl() as ImageManager }
}
```

But Preferences crashes

```
val preferencesModule: Module = applicationContext {
    bean { PreferencesImpl(androidApplication()) as Preferences }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Solution is easy but not so obvious.

Somehow Android Studio imported standalone `startKoin` function instead of specific android function.

So I had to replace

```
import org.koin.standalone.StandAloneContext.startKoin
```

To

```
import org.koin.android.ext.android.startKoin
```

And that works!

Comment: import org.koin.android.ext.android.startKoin is available in production code but not in test. how can I make it available in test code?

Comment: @windchime If you mean jUnit tests I guess you should avoid ext.android =) In other words use standalone context in jUnit.

Comment: this error also occurred when testing. koin + coroutines, seems doesn't work well

this article only epxlain how to use kotlin coroutines https://medium.com/@tonyowen/android-kotlin-coroutines-unit-test-16e984ba35b4

Comment: importing org.koin.android.ext.android.startKoin , startKoin cannot resolve symbol.so it is useless

Comment: I'm in KMM project. so "startKoin" imported from "org.koin.core.context.startKoin" .  is there any issue here?

Comment: Hey but In my case I have same error and my import statement is looks like:
import org.koin.core.context.GlobalContext.startKoin

Answer (score 5):

In my case I needed to make like this:

```
import android.app.Application
 import org.koin.android.ext.koin.androidContext
  import org.koin.android.ext.koin.androidFileProperties
import org.koin.android.ext.koin.androidLogger
import org.koin.android.viewmodel.dsl.viewModel
import org.koin.core.context.startKoin
import org.koin.core.module.Module
import org.koin.dsl.module
class MyApplication : Application() {
override fun onCreate(){
    super.onCreate()
    // start Koin!
    startKoin {
        // Android context
        androidLogger()
        androidContext(this@MyApplication)
        // use the Android context given there
        // load properties from assets/koin.properties file
        androidFileProperties()


        // modules
        modules(myModule)
    }
}
val myModule: Module = module { viewModel { MyViewModel() }}

}
```

and use older dependencies:

```
 implementation("org.koin:koin-android:2.0.1")
implementation("org.koin:koin-android-viewmodel:2.0.1")
```

Comment: it is not working anymore

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue ,
Try to just add this dependency it will be resolved

`// Room
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1"
    kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1" .`

Comment: I'm using Realm database. so, I need to add this?

Answer (score 0):

1. In my case for another situation it wrote this message:

"org.koin.core.error.NoBeanDefFoundException: No definition found for class:'...Actions'. Check your definitions!"

```
private val actions: Actions by inject()

var modules = module(override = true) {
    single<Actions> { ActionsImpl(get()) }
}

@Test
fun test() {
    actions.swipe()
}
```

In this case `Actions` is an interface.

2. Make sure you call a variable *before* `unloadKoinModules(modules)` has been called!
3. Don't use injections with several classes inside.

   ```
   module {
       viewModel {
           FirstViewModel(interactor = get())
           SecondViewModel(interactor = get()) // Remove this
       }
       //// Add a viewmodel here:
       //viewModel {
       //    SecondViewModel(interactor = get())
       //}
   }
   ```

When injected the viewModel in a fragment I got this exception.

```
private val viewModel: FirstViewModel by viewModel()
```