# Cant load a viewmodel from inside afragment using Koin

Tags: android, kotlin, koin

i have a simple Fragment and viewmodel that i wish to use inside the fragment, however it keeps throwing the below error:

```
 Caused by: org.koin.core.error.NoBeanDefFoundException: No definition found for class:'com.me.ui.MovieListViewModel'. Check your definitions!
```

THe viewmodel can be loaded fine on the activity clas but not on the fragment.

Fragment code below

```
class TopMoviesFragment : BaseFragment() {

    private val movieListViewModel: MovieListViewModel by viewModel()
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        movieListViewModel.doSomething()
```

viewmodel code

```
class MovieListViewModel constructor(private val someData: SomeData) : ViewModel() {

     fun doSomething(){
        someData.do()
    }

}
```

Koin setup

```
object AppComponent {
    val getAllModules = listOf(MainAppModule,
            ANotherMOdule,
            networkModule,
            uiModule)
}


val uiModule = module {
    factory { SOmeData(get()) }
    viewModel { MovieListViewModel(get()) }
}


class MovieListApp : Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        startKoin{
            // Koin Android logger
            androidLogger()
            //inject Android context
            androidContext(this@MovieListApp)
            AppComponent.getAllModules}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your imports in MovieListApp class? You might have the wrong import for startkoin{} method.
I suggest you check this question out
[Koin Android: org.koin.error.NoBeanDefFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51195471/koin-android-org-koin-error-nobeandeffoundexception)

Comment: Ok I'll give that a go

Comment: NOpe it did not work, infact `import org.koin.android.ext.android.startKoin` does not exist. i am using import org.koin.core.context.startKoin

Answer (score 0):

THe issue was inside the startKoin.

I had to pass the list of modules inside this:

```
modules(AppComponent.getAllModules)
```